# Trouble send hex (Modbus Packet) via pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, modbus

I am having some trouble with sending the following hex codes 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x0a 0x84 to a serial device (Voltage Sensor) which will return an int for current voltage using Python and pyserial. My code is as follows:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
port=1,
baudrate=38400,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
timeout=0,
xonxoff=0,
rtscts=0)    

ByteStringToSend = "\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x0a\x84"
ser.write(ByteStringToSend)
time.sleep(1)
RecievedData = ""
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    RecievedData = ser.read(1)
return RecievedData
```

The problem is it appears Python is sending each byte as an individual packet see below image from a serial monitor

see image at http://www.centralinfo.com.au/images/SerialOutput.png

The first 8 bytes (00 - 07) is from the python app (note the altinate colors for the different packets) The next 8 bytes (08 - 0f) is a VB.net app sending the same data which works.

My question is how do I send the 8 hex bytes above so it is in one packet (Modbus Protocol) as per the vb.net app?

VB Code for comparison:

```
     ' open the serial port if it is closed
            If Me.SerialPort1.IsOpen = False Then
                Me.SerialPort1.PortName = ComPort
                Me.SerialPort1.BaudRate = "38400" 'Set Baud rate
                Me.SerialPort1.RtsEnable = False ' Set RTS
                Me.SerialPort1.DtrEnable = False ' Set DTR
                Me.SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                Me.SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.Two
                Me.SerialPort1.DataBits = 8 ' Set data length
                Me.SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff
                Me.SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 10000
                Me.SerialPort1.WriteTimeout = 10000
                Me.SerialPort1.Open()
            End If

    Try
            Dim CommandBlock(7) As Byte
            CommandBlock(0) = &H1
            CommandBlock(1) = &H3
            CommandBlock(2) = &H0
            CommandBlock(3) = &H0
            CommandBlock(4) = &H0
            CommandBlock(5) = &H1
            CommandBlock(6) = &HA
            CommandBlock(7) = &H84
            Me.SerialPort1.Write(CommandBlock, 0, CommandBlock.Length)
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
```

Thanks in advance for your time
Chris

Comment: There's no such thing as a serial "packet". What is the software you're using that is telling you they are being sent separate packets?

Comment: Also, you're not sending "hex". Just because you're writing hex in your sourcecode doesn't mean you're sending "hex". You're sending binary data. If you were sending hex, that would mean you were sending ASCII characters of the hex representation of those bytes.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply the monitoring software is Device Monitoring Studio - Raw Data view. When using the VB app all 8 bytes appear in one sudden block then a reply comes back from the device. but the python code when sent appears one byte at a time, meaning when the request is sent one byte shown in sequence (about 100-200 milliseconds apart)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654031/pyserial-sends-ascii-data-but-recieving-device-does-not-respond-to-it?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117580/problems-with-sending-commands-over-pyserial?rq=1 ?

Comment: It appears similar, however the answer does not suit my case. My problem is pyserial appears to be sending the data to slow and appears as separate " 1 byte packets" as per the image above http://www.centralinfo.com.au/images/SerialOutput.png . where as vb.net sends all bytes through quickly appearing as a 8byte packet

Comment: What are the com port settings of the VB app ?

Comment: Hi Alexandre, I have edited the above question to show the vb.net connection properties

Answer (score 1):

Your VB app enables XON/XOFF protocol, while your python app does not. Without XON/XOFF turned on, I suspect that your python app is waiting for a certain amount of time between each bytes before sending it, thus the receiving device sees each byte as an individual "packet".

Comment: Well spotted I'll try it out and let you know :D

Comment: I have changed the following line (xonxoff=1) unfortunately it gives the same result, where it comes up one byte at a time appearing as multiple packets